# Laravel 5.5 ThrottleRequest middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Does anyone have info on how to implement the `ThrottleRequest` middleware in Laravel 5.5?

I'm not clear on the meaning of the `decayMinutes` parameter in particular: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.html

I understand how to apply it to a route, I just am not sure what reaosnable parameters would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`decayMinutes` - it's a time within your limit will be counted. Technically limits is a value with TTL (Time To Live) `$decayMinutes * 60` secs in cache that increments on every hit. When TTL is over value automatically will be destroyed in cache and new hits count will be start.

Look at [RateLimit::hit()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php) code. It's pretty clear:

```
/**
 * Increment the counter for a given key for a given decay time.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  float|int  $decayMinutes
 * @return int
 */
public function hit($key, $decayMinutes = 1)
{
    $this->cache->add(
        $key.':timer', $this->availableAt($decayMinutes * 60), $decayMinutes
    );
    $added = $this->cache->add($key, 0, $decayMinutes);
    $hits = (int) $this->cache->increment($key);
    if (! $added && $hits == 1) {
        $this->cache->put($key, 1, $decayMinutes);
    }
    return $hits;
}
```

If you want to limit some activity by 10 hits per 5 minutes, than `decayMinutes` must be 5.

Answer (score 7):

I understand `decayMinutes` as the retention time. For intance, if you want to give a 10 try to login with wrong password but if he tries for 11 times, the user gets blocked for the number of minutes specified in `decayMinutes`. If you specify 10 minutes as your `decayMinutes`, the user is blocked for 10 minutes

Comment: From having read the source code, this is my understanding too.

Comment: This is wrong answer. `decayMinutes` (in Laravel 5.5) is not a block time.

Comment: I guess login block time is an example, and it does work mostly the same way for throttling. Just replace 'login attempt' with 'unique url requested'. If you don't make any page or api requests for $decayMinutes minutes then the throttle counter resets.

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk he's absolutely right. You can check out [ThrottleLoginTrait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ThrottlesLogins.php#L118) for the decay minute.

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti if I check the ThrottleRequest Class ( we are talking about throttling Requests not Logins ) , I see that Alexander is right.